# 1 Modem with 3 separate networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have duplex that I just purchased and I am going to supply internet to each apartment. There will be a common internet used for the whole building which will be used for doorbell and security cameras.

I also want each apartment to have it's own separate internet(each room has hard wired Ethernet outlets) and Wi-Fi connections, but I do not want Apt 1 and Apt 2 to have any access to each others network by default (unless neighbours share Wi-Fi passwords).

Is this possible? If so, what would be a good way to accomplish this? I have attached a diagram to illustrate. thank you for any assistance

[image]

Comment: a home network should branch like a tree, and never loop. so you will need three routers for 3 networks, and each should act as a firewall. that will keep everyone out of everyone else's business, though you will have to add a couple firewall rules to prevent the apartments from accessing the doorbells and cameras. connect one router behind the modem, and two routers behind the first one. if you use standard home internet gateway routers, most of it will just work. the only issue you will have is if your users want to forward ports.

Comment: Does this diagram show the actual HW connections?

Comment: no, nothing is currently implemented

Answer (score 1):

I assume the modem has a router build in, otherwise the "common internet devices" wouldn't be able to access the internet. If not, you need to connect them to a router as well. Also, if your modem does not have a router build in you need to check if you can connect more then one routers to your modem (e.g. you might need to establish more then one PPPoE connection, this is not always possible)

If you use the WAN ports of a router to connect them to the modem there shouldn't be any connection possible between the devices connected to the routers. You might want to make sure the router is not accessible to your tenants of the apartment, otherwise there might be a security issue (depending on the specific setup).

An alternative setup would be to use VLAN/Firewall to control access to internet and across your LAN. This will require a different setup and possibly different HW (depending on what you already have).

Comment: do you connect all 3 routers to directly to the modem or do you daisy chain them together as @Frank Thomas suggested?

Comment: As I said in my answer, assuming your modem is offering a PPPoE connection it depends on how many simultaneous PPPoE connection you can establish. If possible I would connect them all directly to the modem (easier and better security). Check with your ISP.

Comment: Most modems will have only one output port. if there is more than one, the device is more likely to be a router, than a modem, in which case you would only need 2 additional routers..